# Related; adding same pageaction in configuration page in M2

Tags: magento2

I tried your method , its successfully adding "Clear Category Cache" button in admin->Catalog->Category.
But my question is that "How can i add the Reset button in admin->configuration->'my_module_configuration'->'specific_tab'"?

Answer (score 0):

Steps to be followed:

Step 1. Register your module: app/code/Dotsquares/ModuleConfig/registration.php

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Dotsquares_ModuleConfig',
    __DIR__
);
```

Step 2. Create module.xml file: app/code/Dotsquares/ModuleConfig/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Dotsquares_ModuleConfig" />
</config>
```

Step 3. Create system xml file in Admin: app/code/Dotsquares/ModuleConfig/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="dotsquares" translate="label" sortOrder="11">
            <label>Dotsquares</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="module" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="998" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Dotsquares Config</label>
            <tab>dotsquares</tab>
            <resource>Dotsquares_ModuleConfig::config_moduleconfig</resource>

            <group id="configlocate" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Configuration</label>
                <field id="reset" translate="label comment" sortOrder="2" type="obscure" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" >
                    <label>Reset Form Data</label>  <frontend_model>Dotsquares\ModuleConfig\Block\System\Config\Synchronize</frontend_model>
                </field>
            </group>

        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Step 5. Create Block File: app/code/Dotsquares/ModuleConfig/Block/System/Config/Synchronize.php

```
<?php

namespace Dotsquares\ModuleConfig\Block\System\Config;

class Synchronize extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field
{
    protected $_template = 'Dotsquares_ModuleConfig::system/config/collect.phtml';

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function render(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $element->unsScope()->unsCanUseWebsiteValue()->unsCanUseDefaultValue();
        return parent::render($element);
    }

    protected function _getElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
    {
        return $this->_toHtml();
    }

    public function getAjaxUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('dotsquares_moduleconfig/system_config/collect');
    }

    public function getButtonHtml()
    {
        $button = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button'
        )->setData(
            [
                'id' => 'synchronize_button',
                'label' => __('Reset'),
            ]
        );

        return $button->toHtml();
    }
}
```

Step 6. Create phtml file in adminhtml folder: app/code/Dotsquares/ModuleConfig/view/adminhtml/templates/system/config/collect.phtml

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'prototype'
    ], function(jQuery){

        var collectSpan = jQuery('#collect_span');

        jQuery('#collect_button').click(function () {
            var params = {};
            new Ajax.Request('<?php echo $block->getAjaxUrl() ?>', {
                parameters:     params,
                loaderArea:     false,
                asynchronous:   true,
                onCreate: function() {
                    collectSpan.find('.collected').hide();
                    collectSpan.find('.processing').show();
                    jQuery('#collect_message_span').text('');
                },
                onSuccess: function(response) {
                    collectSpan.find('.processing').hide();

                    var resultText = '';
                    if (response.status > 200) {
                        resultText = response.statusText;
                    } else {
                        resultText = 'Success';
                        collectSpan.find('.collected').show();
                    }
                    jQuery('form').reset();

                    var json = response.responseJSON;
                    if (typeof json.time != 'undefined') {
                        jQuery('#form').find('.value .time').text(json.time);
                    }
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
<?php echo $block->getButtonHtml() ?>
```

Comment: thank you for the replay. but i would like to tell you that i have done the above steps.

Comment: can you please tell me "how can i reset form data by clicking on the Reset button"?
i want to delete data from table named "core_config_data",
here are the fields i want to delete from database by clicking on Reset button :-
(1)store_credentials
(2)store_secret
(3)api_key

Comment: In the phtml, where I have written this code <?php echo $block->getButtonHtml() ?>
Write javascript and make the form reset

Kindly look above my modifed answer, I have amended phtml file code

Comment: i appriciate your fast & satisfied answer. thank you so much .
is that possible to connect with you ? (skype , LinkedIn , Whatsapp)

Comment: ok, we can connect over LinkedIn. Find there Navneet Sharma

Comment: hy ! can you plz help me with my another question, i wanna get current store_view_id (scope_id) in magento2 . (i have posted a question for the same)